# How should I represent a summation sequence in Python using numbers from raw_input?

Tags: python-2.7

Okay, so I have this python program that asks for x coordinates and lets say for example the user enters these 5 x coordinates all at oncee. x = 3, 5, 6, 7, 9. After storing these 5 "x" coordinates how do I TAKE them and use them in a summation pattern such as this one for example:

x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5

Here is my code so far:

from ast import literal_eval

num = int(raw_input("N of points: "))

x_input = raw_input("X:")

y_input = raw_input("Y:")

x_coords = map(float, x_input.split())

y_coords = map(float, y_input.split())

print x_coords

print y_coords

Comment: can you please share the piece of code you have already?

Comment: I just adde dit to the post, please check

Comment: thanks. can you also explain what do you mean by `use them in a summation pattern`. do you just want to calculate a sum?

Comment: Basically I want to take the x coordinates that the user enters and SUM them all up in the order they were entered using a for loop. So if I get the x coordinates 5, 4, 3, 6, 8 how do I take these coordinates and sum them all up with a for loop?

Comment: In other words I want to find the sum...

Answer (score 0):

I guess if the input is "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" and you want to sum all numbers your go, then you want to split it by ",", then trim whitespaces, then convert to floats and then sum

in this case something like this should work

```
>>> x_input = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
>>> sum(float(x.strip()) for x in x_input.split(","))
15.0
```

Comment: What does the strip do in this case?

Comment: Removes possible spaces around numbers after splitting